# how can i make flexible imageusing max-width in css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a website for mobile but I have problem with flexible images. I use max-width:100% and height:auto but when I reload the page I get only a liitle part of the image, that looks like a black line...Please can anyone help me. What ca I do, because I spend a lot of time with this and no result.....

This is the part of css that I think is needed:

```
.mobilenav{display: block;}

/*Class for the logo of the website*/

.logo1{background:  url(images/logobank8.png) no-repeat;
      margin-top: 2%;
      margin-left: 20% ;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
         }
/*Class for a transparent header which is put at the begining of the page*/ 
.header1{ background: rgba(74, 84, 91, 0.7);
          width: 110%;
          height: 50px; }
```

And this is the html part:

```
<div class="mobilenav">
                    <div class="header1">
                            <div class="logo1"></div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close because you've provided us nothing to analyze. Code, please.

Comment: Have you tried changing max-width to just width: 100%; ?

Comment: I try width:100% and height:100% but when I resize the browser window the image do not scale

Comment: So the image is a background that's set on a div in CSS? It's not in the source markup?

Comment: Yes it is set on a div like The code above shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the image's parent spans the width you're trying fill, you can use `width: 100%;` to scale your image to that full available available width. * Note that `max-width: 100%;` only restrains the image from expanding beyond that width.

As your image appears as a background on a div, and is not in the source itself, you could use the following `background-size: cover;` approach from CSS Tricks (http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/):

```
.logo1 { 
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

`.logo1` will need to have a width and height set as well, but I'd leave that to your specific needs to determine.